# how to depend on externally generated classes properly in sbt?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

I have a java-only mult-project sbt build.  I have a project that builds a .war file (with [xsbt-web-plugin](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin)). It depends on other projects that build .jars that get bundled into the .war.

In the .jar projects, I need to run an external process that generates .class files after compilation, and have those classes get bundled into the .jars packaged for the project.

So I can have a task that depends on `compile` and uses the classpath and output directory like this:

```
val ClassGen = TaskKey[Int]("generate-classes", "generates classes")
val ClassGenTask = ClassGen <<= doClassGen()

def doClassGen() =
  (streams in Compile,
   compile in Compile,
   classDirectory in Compile,
   fullClasspath in Compile) map {

     ...
     "command here" !
   }
```

This seems to cause the task to depend on compilation.  If I have `package` depend on my task, I think this will all run before the .jar file is built:

```
sbt.Keys.`package` <<=  (sbt.Keys.`package` in Compile) dependsOn ClassGen
```

But... when I execute the `package` task in the dependant project (the .war project), it does **not** seem to cause `package` to be executed in the dependencies.  I have tried turning on `exportJars` to no avail.

I have also seen cases where my classes get generated but do not appear in the .jar file.  This seems to be due to the `package` task being run before my ClassGen task.

I'm confused about how I can depend on the output of a post-compilation, external process task that generates classes, and have that dependency sequence properly with inter-project dependencies.  I have looked into `exportedProducts` as per [here](https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin) which seems to be probably the thing that dependent projects would look for, but am out of ideas for how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your output directory to `products in Compile`. If you check what `package` depends on, you'll see that it depends on `compile:products` (*last line*):

```
> inspect tree compile:package
[info] compile:package = Task[java.io.File]
[info]   +-compile:packageBin = Task[java.io.File]
[info]     +-compile:packageBin::packageConfiguration = Task[sbt.Package$Configuration]
[info]     | +-compile:packageBin::mappings = Task[scala.collection.Seq[scala.Tuple2[java.io.File, java.lang.String]]]
[info]     | | +-compile:products = Task[scala.collection.Seq[java.io.File]]
```

Seems like you could add your folder to which you generate classes to compile products. You could do this by adding setting

```
products in Compile += (target in Compile).value / "my_generated_classes"
```

given that you generate the classes to the `target/my_generated_classes` directory.

PS. I assume you generated binary classes and not sources which must be compiled.